# Cannot show object info

Tags: c#, oop

I created an abstract class and two classes inherit from this abstract class. Then I created an abstract class type List and tried to fill it with objects of two classes inheriting this abstract class. But when I try to display information on an object field, it outputs either 0 or null. I am new to c# so I apologize in advance for the stupid question.

```
    public List<Car> AutosList = new List<Car>();
    public void AddItems() {
        //Adding Passenger Cars
        Passenger car1 = new Passenger(1001, "Seltos", "Kias", 22000.50, condition.excellent, 2020, type.passenger, 5);
        Passenger car2 = new Passenger(1002, "Seltos", "Kias", 19500.50, condition.bad, 2019, type.passenger, 5);
        Passenger car3 = new Passenger(1003, "Spark", "Chevrolet", 10000.50, condition.excellent, 2020, type.passenger, 5);
        Passenger car4 = new Passenger(1004, "Spark", "Chevrolet", 8000.50, condition.bad, 2018, type.passenger, 5);
        Passenger car5 = new Passenger(1005, "Nexia", "Chevrolet", 12000.50, condition.excellent, 2020, type.passenger, 5);

        //Adding Industrial Cars
        Industrial car6 = new Industrial(1006, "Kamaz", "Lada", 45000.50, condition.excellent, 2020, type.industrial, 10000.20);
        Industrial car7 = new Industrial(1007, "Kamaz", "Lada", 20000.50, condition.excellent, 2018, type.industrial, 10000.20);
        Industrial car8 = new Industrial(1008, "Cat", "Man", 67000.50, condition.excellent, 2020, type.industrial, 10000.20);
        
        Car[] AllCars = new Car[] { car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8 };

        foreach (var item in AllCars)
        {
            AutosList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void ShowItem() {
        foreach (var item in AutosList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We probably need to see the class definitions - especially the constructors.

Comment: Probably unrelated: Why is there a `type.passenger`/ `type.industrial` param if the class already specifies the type?